# Change position of radio buttons from vertical to horizontal in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This code generates a questionnaire from a set of questions. The code generates a new sheet with all questions and options in form of radio button. The code right now displays all the options one below the other. How do we change the layout of the radio buttons and display all the options in one row instead of one below the other?

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Worksheets("Raw Data").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Worksheets("Questions").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Worksheets("Survey Results").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

If TextBox1.Value = "" And TextBox2.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox " Please provide ID and Name"
        Exit Sub

    ElseIf TextBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox " Please provide ID"
        Exit Sub

    ElseIf TextBox2.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox " Please provide Name"
        Exit Sub
End If

Worksheets("Questions").Unprotect
Worksheets("Questions").Range("SV3") = TextBox1.Value
Z = Worksheets("Questions").Range("SV6").Value

If Z = "" Then
        b = 0
    ElseIf (Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A" & Z).Value) = 1 Then
        b = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A" & Z).Value
End If

If (Worksheets("Questions").Range("SV4").Value = Trim(TextBox1.Value)) And (b = 1) Then
        MsgBox " You have already completed the survey !!!"
        Unload UserForm1
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Worksheets("Questions").Range("SV4").Value <> Trim(TextBox1.Value) Or b = "" Then

        Unload UserForm1
        NextRow = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B" & NextRow) = TextBox1.Value
        Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B" & NextRow).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B" & NextRow).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("C" & NextRow) = TextBox2.Value
        Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("C" & NextRow).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("C" & NextRow).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
End If

Worksheets("Questions").Unprotect
'Worksheets("Questions").Range("A:A").Select
'Selection.AutoFilter
Worksheets("Questions").Range("$A$1:$F$94").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Ques"
NextRow = Worksheets("Questions").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Questions").Range("B2:B" & NextRow).Copy
Sheets("Raw Data").Range("D1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Worksheets("Questions").Range("A:A").AutoFilter

'****************************

Dim lngCtrlLeft         As Long
Dim lngCtrlTop          As Long
Dim intLoop             As Integer
Dim intQues             As Integer
Dim intColType          As Integer
Dim intLbl              As Integer
Dim intCtrlStartRow     As Integer
Dim ole                 As Excel.OLEObject
Dim wksControl          As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wksQuestionnaire    As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wbkNew              As Excel.Workbook


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.StatusBar = "Creating Questionnaire..."
Set wksControl = shtControl

wksControl.Unprotect
Set wbkNew = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set wksQuestionnaire = wbkNew.Worksheets.Add
'Set wksQuestionnaire = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(N).Name = "NewForm"
wksQuestionnaire.Name = "Questionnaire"

wksQuestionnaire.DrawingObjects.Delete

lngCtrlLeft = 20
lngCtrlTop = 25

intColType = 1
intLbl = 2

intCtrlStartRow = 1


For intLoop = intCtrlStartRow To wksControl.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    Select Case wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value

        Case "Heading"
            Set ole = wksQuestionnaire.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.Label.1")

        Case "Ques"
            Set ole = wksQuestionnaire.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.Label.1")
            intQues = intQues + 1
            Application.StatusBar = "Ques " & intQues & "..."

        Case "Radio"
            Set ole = wksQuestionnaire.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1")
            ole.Object.GroupName = "QGrp" & CStr(intQues)

        Case "Check"
            Set ole = wksQuestionnaire.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
            ole.Object.GroupName = "QGrp" & CStr(intQues)

        Case "Text"
            Set ole = wksQuestionnaire.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

        Case "Spin"
            Set ole = wksQuestionnaire.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.SpinButton.1")

        Case "Button"
            Set ole = wksQuestionnaire.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")

    End Select

    If wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value = "Heading" Then
        ole.Left = lngCtrlLeft - 5
        lngCtrlTop = lngCtrlTop + 15
        ole.Top = lngCtrlTop
        ole.Object.Font.Size = 15
        ole.Object.Font.Bold = True
    End If

    If wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value = "Button" Then
        ole.Left = lngCtrlLeft - 5
        lngCtrlTop = lngCtrlTop + 15
        ole.Top = lngCtrlTop
    End If

    If wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value = "Ques" Then
        ole.Left = lngCtrlLeft - 5
        lngCtrlTop = lngCtrlTop + 15
        ole.Top = lngCtrlTop
    Else
        ole.Left = lngCtrlLeft
        ole.Top = lngCtrlTop
    End If

    If wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value <> "Text" And wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value <> "Button" And wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value <> "Spin" Then

            If wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value = "Ques" Then
                ole.Object.Caption = CStr(intQues) & ". " & wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intLbl).Value
            Else
                ole.Object.Caption = wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intLbl).Value
            End If
            ole.Object.WordWrap = False
            ole.Object.AutoSize = True

        ElseIf wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value = "Spin" Then
            ole.Left = ole.Left + 35
            ole.LinkedCell = ole.TopLeftCell.Offset(1, -1).Address
            ole.Object.Max = 0
            ole.Object.Max = 5
        ElseIf wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value = "Button" Then
            ole.Object.AutoSize = True
            ole.Object.WordWrap = True
            'ole.Object.Height = True
            ole.Object.Caption = wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intLbl).Value
            ole.Height = 23.5
            ole.Width = 93
            ole.Name = "Submit"

            Dim Code1 As String
            Code1 = vbNullString
            Code1 = Code1 & "Private Sub Submit_Click()" & vbCrLf

            Code1 = Code1 & "Dim lngAnsRow As Long" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Dim wbkCollate As Excel.Worksheet" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Dim wbkResponse As Excel.Worksheet" & vbCrLf

            Code1 = Code1 & "lngAnsRow = 1" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Worksheets(""Raw Data"").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Worksheets(""Questions"").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Worksheets(""Survey Results"").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Worksheets(""Questions"").Unprotect" & vbCrLf

            Code1 = Code1 & "Set wbkCollate = Worksheets(""Raw Data"")" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "lngAnsRow = lngAnsRow + 1" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Set wbkResponse = Worksheets(""Questionnaire"")" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Call GetAns(wbkResponse, wbkCollate, lngAnsRow)" & vbCrLf

            Code1 = Code1 & "Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(""Raw Data"")" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "LastRow1 = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, ""C"").End(xlUp).Row" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "If Worksheets(""Raw Data"").Cells(LastRow1, 1).Value = 1 Then" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   Load UserForm3" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   UserForm3.Show" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   Application.DisplayAlerts = False" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   WorkSheets(""Questionnaire"").Delete" & vbCrLf
            'Code1 = Code1 & "   Application.DisplayAlerts = True" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "End If" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "If Worksheets(""Raw Data"").Cells(LastRow1, 1).Value <> 1 Then" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   MsgBox ""Please answer the questions to proceed further""" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   Sheets(""Questionnaire"").Activate" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "End If" & vbCrLf

            Code1 = Code1 & "GoTo ExitEarly" & vbCrLf

            Code1 = Code1 & "ExitEarly:" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   On Error Resume Next" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   Set wbkCollate = Nothing" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   Set wbkResponse = Nothing" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   Erase varFiles" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   Erase varFile" & vbCrLf

            Code1 = Code1 & "End Sub" & vbCrLf


            Code1 = Code1 & "Function GetAns(wksSrc As Worksheet, wksTgt As Worksheet, lngAnsRow As Long)" & vbCrLf

            Code1 = Code1 & "Dim objControl As OLEObject" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Dim strQues As String" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Dim strAns  As String" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Dim lngCol  As Long" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "lngcCol = 3" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(""Raw Data"")" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "k = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, ""D"").End(xlUp).Column" & vbCrLf

            Code1 = Code1 & "For Each objControl In wksSrc.OLEObjects" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   If TypeName(objControl.Object) =""Label"" Then" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       lngCol = lngCol + 1" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       strQues = objControl.Object.Caption" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       strAns = "" " & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   End If" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   If TypeName(objControl.Object) =""OptionButton"" Then" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       If objControl.Object.Value = True Then" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           strAns = strAns & objControl.Object.Caption" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           UinptUsgFrq = getRskWghtNum(strQues, strAns)" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           LastRow1 = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, ""C"").End(xlUp).Row" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           wksTgt.Cells((LastRow1), (k)) = UinptUsgFrq" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           k = k + 1" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       End If" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   End If" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   If TypeName(objControl.Object) =""TextBox"" Then" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       If Trim(objControl.Object.Text) <> """" Then" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           strAns = strAns & objControl.Object.Text" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           UinptUsgFrq = getRskWghtNum(strQues, strAns)" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           LastRow1 = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, ""C"").End(xlUp).Row" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           wksTgt.Cells((LastRow1), (k)) = UinptUsgFrq" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           k = k + 1" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       End If" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   End If" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   If TypeName(objControl.Object) =""CheckBox"" Then" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       If objControl.Object.Value = True Then" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           strAns = strAns & objControl.Object.Caption" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           UinptUsgFrq = getRskWghtNum(strQues, strAns)" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           LastRow1 = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, ""C"").End(xlUp).Row" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           wksTgt.Cells((LastRow1), (k)) = UinptUsgFrq" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           k = k + 1" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       End If" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   End If" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Next objControl" & vbCrLf

            Code1 = Code1 & "Set objControl = Nothing" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "End Function" & vbCrLf


            Code1 = Code1 & "Function getRskWghtNum(strQues, strAns)" & vbCrLf

            Code1 = Code1 & "intStartRow = 2" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "intStartRow1 = 2" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "strquest = Split(strQues,"". "")" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "strQues1 = strquest(1)" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "strAns1 = Trim(strAns)" & vbCrLf

            Code1 = Code1 & "Do While Trim(Sheets(""Questions"").Cells(intStartRow1, 2)) <> """ & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   If Trim((Sheets(""Questions"").Cells(intStartRow1, 2).Value) = strQues1) Then" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       If Trim((Sheets(""Questions"").Cells(intStartRow, 2).Value)) = strAns1 Then" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           getRskWghtNum = Trim(Sheets(""Questions"").Cells(intStartRow, 3).Value)" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "           Exit Do" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       End If" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       intStartRow = intStartRow + 1" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   Else" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       intStartRow1 = intStartRow1 + 1" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "       intStartRow = intStartRow1" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "   End If" & vbCrLf
            Code1 = Code1 & "Loop" & vbCrLf

            Code1 = Code1 & "End Function" & vbCrLf

            With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveSheet.CodeName).CodeModule
                'With Worksheets(wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intLbl).Value)
                'With ActiveWorkbook.ole.Object.CodeModule
                Nextline = CountOfLines + 1
                .insertlines Nextline, Code1

            End With

        ElseIf wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value = "Text" Then
            ole.Object.AutoSize = False
            ole.Object.WordWrap = True
            ole.Object.IntegralHeight = False
            ole.Width = 175
            ole.Height = 17
    End If

    lngCtrlTop = lngCtrlTop + 16

Next intLoop

wksControl.Protect
DoEvents
wbkNew.Activate

With ActiveWindow
    .DisplayGridlines = False
    .DisplayHeadings = False
End With

Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("D1:D5").EntireRow.Insert
Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("A1:A3").EntireColumn.Insert

wksQuestionnaire.Rows(CStr(ole.TopLeftCell.Offset(3).Row) & ":" & CStr(wksQuestionnaire.Rows.Count)).Hidden = True
Application.StatusBar = "Saving Questionnaire to Desktop..."

Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("B3:K5").Merge
Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("B3").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("B3").Value = "Customer Satisfaction Survey - Questionarie"
Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("B3").Font.ColorIndex = 1
Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("B3").Font.Size = 20
Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("B3").Font.Bold = True
Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("B3:K5").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("B3:K5").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("B3:K5").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 21.57

Set ole = Nothing
Set wksControl = Nothing
Set wksQuestionnaire = Nothing
Set wbkNew = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure why you posted all this code. But to me it seems that you merely have to change the lines where the `ole` gets assigned their `top` and `left`. To align them vertically the `Left` is always the same namely `lngCtrlLeft - 5` and the top is always increased by 15 with `lngCtrlTop = lngCtrlTop + 15` (apparently that's the height of these options). So, why not change the `Left` and increase it by `ole.Width + 10` (+10 just to add some space between them) and keep the `Top` always the same?

Comment: I tried doing that, unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: If wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value = "Button" Then
            ole.Left = lngCtrlLeft + ole.Width + 10
            ole.Top = lngCtrlTop + 15
        End If

Comment: You should read this page - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - and then try and post some code that shows the basic problem that you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is not tested, but it may do what you want:

Add the following Dim with the rest of your variable dimensioning:

```
Dim numOptions As Integer
```

Add this bit of code to replace the bit you are currently using to set the top and left positions of each of your controls:

```
If wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value = "Heading" Then
    ole.Left = lngCtrlLeft - 5
    lngCtrlTop = lngCtrlTop + 15
    ole.Top = lngCtrlTop
    ole.Object.Font.Size = 15
    ole.Object.Font.Bold = True

ElseIf wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value = "Button" Then
    ole.Left = lngCtrlLeft - 5
    lngCtrlTop = lngCtrlTop + 15
    ole.Top = lngCtrlTop

ElseIf wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value = "Ques" Then
    ole.Left = lngCtrlLeft - 5
    lngCtrlTop = lngCtrlTop + 15
    ole.Top = lngCtrlTop
    numOptions = 0

ElseIf wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value = "Radio" Then
    ole.Left = lngCtrlLeft + numOptions * 30 ' the "30" might need to be changed to provide appropriate spacing
    lngCtrlTop = lngCtrlTop - 16 ' to get rid of the effect of adding 16 at the end of the loop
    ole.Top = lngCtrlTop
    numOptions = numOptions + 1

Else
    ole.Left = lngCtrlLeft
    ole.Top = lngCtrlTop
End If
```

The code assumes that the radio buttons ("Radio" in column A) for each question immediately the question ("Ques" in column A).

(If the code doesn't work, let me know and I will delete the answer.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it worked. But there was an overlap between question and the radio buttons. So I tweaked it a bit: ElseIf wksControl.Cells(intLoop, intColType).Value = "Radio" Then
    ole.Left = lngCtrlLeft + numOptions * 90 ' the "30" might need to be changed to provide appropriate spacing
    lngCtrlTop = lngCtrlTop ' to get rid of the effect of adding 16 at the end of the loop
    ole.Top = lngCtrlTop
    lngCtrlTop = lngCtrlTop - 16
    numOptions = numOptions + 1      This also works partially but there is very little gap between radio buttons and next question.

Comment: @user1778266 Without seeing the information you are putting in for the questions and answers, there's not much we can do to help you with the tweaking.  (Maybe something could be done by using ole.Height and ole.Width properties [if they exist], but it would require a much better understanding of your code than I have time for.)  You can tweak the location of the top of your questions by changing `lngCtrlTop = lngCtrlTop + 15` in the section that is setting positions for the "Ques". `